# How to group and filter this array of hashes. Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have this data:

```
@complete_transactions = [{"timestamp"=>"2018-01-18T02:57:34.959Z", "toAddress"=>"Alice", "amount"=>"50"},
 {"timestamp"=>"2018-01-18T02:57:35.016Z", "fromAddress"=>"Alice", "toAddress"=>"Bob", "amount"=>"12.5"},
 {"timestamp"=>"2018-01-18T16:53:16.747Z", "toAddress"=>"50", "amount"=>"50"},
 {"timestamp"=>"2018-01-18T16:53:27.572Z", "fromAddress"=>"50", "toAddress"=>"alice", "amount"=>"50"},
 {"timestamp"=>"2018-01-18T16:53:38.853Z", "fromAddress"=>"alice", "toAddress"=>"Alice", "amount"=>"50"},
 {"timestamp"=>"2018-01-23T23:35:03.792Z", "fromAddress"=>"Alice", "toAddress"=>"alice", "amount"=>"10"},
 {"timestamp"=>"2018-01-23T23:35:25.464Z", "fromAddress"=>"Alice", "toAddress"=>"Bob", "amount"=>"1"},
 {"timestamp"=>"2018-01-23T23:35:48.835Z", "fromAddress"=>"Alice", "toAddress"=>"Bob", "amount"=>"1"},
 {"timestamp"=>"2018-01-23T23:47:46.485Z", "fromAddress"=>"Alice", "toAddress"=>"Bob", "amount"=>"1"},
 {"timestamp"=>"2018-01-23T23:48:31.953Z", "fromAddress"=>"Alice", "toAddress"=>"Bobz", "amount"=>"1"},
 {"timestamp"=>"2018-01-24T18:11:04.444Z", "fromAddress"=>"Alice", "toAddress"=>"Bobz", "amount"=>"1"},
 {"timestamp"=>"2018-01-24T18:28:40.680Z", "fromAddress"=>"Alice", "toAddress"=>"bob", "amount"=>"3"},
 {"timestamp"=>"2018-01-24T18:36:53.179Z", "fromAddress"=>"Alice", "toAddress"=>"Sally", "amount"=>"3"},
 {"timestamp"=>"2018-01-24T18:39:14.926Z", "fromAddress"=>"Alice", "toAddress"=>"Sally", "amount"=>"3"},
 {"timestamp"=>"2018-01-24T18:39:40.937Z", "fromAddress"=>"Alice", "toAddress"=>"Sally", "amount"=>"3"},
 {"timestamp"=>"2018-01-24T18:40:11.686Z", "fromAddress"=>"Alice", "toAddress"=>"bob", "amount"=>"2"},
 {"timestamp"=>"2018-01-24T18:40:13.720Z", "fromAddress"=>"Alice", "toAddress"=>"bob", "amount"=>"2"},
 {"timestamp"=>"2018-01-24T18:41:32.832Z", "fromAddress"=>"Alice", "toAddress"=>"bob", "amount"=>"2"},
 {"timestamp"=>"2018-01-24T18:49:10.052Z", "fromAddress"=>"Alice", "toAddress"=>"bob", "amount"=>"2"},
 {"timestamp"=>"2018-01-24T18:49:11.729Z", "fromAddress"=>"Alice", "toAddress"=>"bob", "amount"=>"2"},
 {"timestamp"=>"2018-01-24T18:50:09.862Z", "fromAddress"=>"Alice", "toAddress"=>"bob", "amount"=>"2"},
 {"timestamp"=>"2018-01-24T19:14:46.326Z", "fromAddress"=>"Alice", "toAddress"=>"bob", "amount"=>"2"},
 {"timestamp"=>"2018-01-24T20:29:30.973Z", "fromAddress"=>"Alice", "toAddress"=>"Bob", "amount"=>"3"},
 {"timestamp"=>"2018-01-24T20:31:37.491Z", "fromAddress"=>"Alice", "toAddress"=>"bob", "amount"=>"2"},
 {"timestamp"=>"2018-01-24T20:35:06.693Z", "fromAddress"=>"Alice", "toAddress"=>"bob", "amount"=>"2"},
 {"timestamp"=>"2018-01-24T21:29:21.465Z", "fromAddress"=>"Alice", "toAddress"=>"bob", "amount"=>"2"},
 {"timestamp"=>"2018-01-24T21:29:27.637Z", "fromAddress"=>"Alice", "toAddress"=>"bozb", "amount"=>"2"},
 {"timestamp"=>"2018-01-26T19:04:56.197Z", "fromAddress"=>"Alice", "toAddress"=>"bob", "amount"=>"2"},
 {"timestamp"=>"2018-01-28T19:53:12.502Z", "toAddress"=>"1444", "amount"=>"50"},
 {"timestamp"=>"2018-01-28T19:53:21.318Z", "fromAddress"=>"1444", "toAddress"=>"0297bc77", "amount"=>"1"},
 {"timestamp"=>"2018-01-28T19:53:30.947Z", "fromAddress"=>"1444", "toAddress"=>"0297bc77", "amount"=>"1"},
 {"timestamp"=>"2018-01-28T19:54:11.119Z", "fromAddress"=>"1444", "toAddress"=>"0297bc77", "amount"=>"1"},
 {"timestamp"=>"2018-01-28T21:26:58.551Z", "fromAddress"=>"1444", "toAddress"=>"Alice", "amount"=>"1"},
 {"timestamp"=>"2018-01-28T21:28:13.499Z", "fromAddress"=>"1444", "toAddress"=>"Alice", "amount"=>"2"},
 {"timestamp"=>"2018-01-28T21:31:47.454Z", "fromAddress"=>"1444", "toAddress"=>"something else", "amount"=>"2"},
 {"timestamp"=>"2018-01-28T21:39:16.644Z", "fromAddress"=>"1444", "toAddress"=>"Alice", "amount"=>"3"},
 {"timestamp"=>"2018-01-28T21:39:41.527Z", "fromAddress"=>"1444", "toAddress"=>"Alice", "amount"=>"2"},
```

What I'd like is to group the data by the `toAddress` field and total the amounts.

I'd like something like this (notice timestamp is irrelevant):

```
[
   {
    'toAddress' => 'bob', amount: '20', fromAddress: ['Alice', '1444']
   },
   {
    'toAddress' => 'Sally', amount: '9', fromAddress: ['Alice'],
   },
   ...
]
```

Any suggestions on how to do this?

This results in a correct data I think... but feels gross:

```
 complete_transactions.group_by {|trans| trans['toAddress']}.map do |group, transactions|
  transactions.reduce do |h1, h2|
    h1.merge(h2) do |key, old, new|
      if key == 'amount'
        old.to_i + new.to_i
      elsif key == 'fromAddress'
        [old, new].flatten.uniq
      else
        old
      end
    end
  end
end
```

leads to the right outcome, but it feels gross. Is there a better way?

Here's a small sample of data and the desired outcome:

```
 transactions
=> [{"timestamp"=>"2018-01-23T23:48:31.953Z", "fromAddress"=>"Alice", "toAddress"=>"Bobz", "amount"=>"1"}, {"timestamp"=>"2018-01-24T18:11:04.444Z", "fromAddress"=>"Alice", "toAddress"=>"Bobz", "amount"=>"1"}, {"timestamp"=>"2018-01-24T18:11:04.444Z", "fromAddress"=>"Another", "toAddress"=>"Bobz", "amount"=>"1"}]


transactions.reduce do |h1, h2|
irb(main):007:1* h1.merge(h2) do |key, old, new|
irb(main):008:2*   if key == 'amount'
irb(main):009:3>      old.to_i + new.to_i
irb(main):010:3>   elsif key == 'fromAddress'
irb(main):011:3>      [old, new].flatten.uniq
irb(main):012:3>   else
irb(main):013:3*      old
irb(main):014:3>   end
irb(main):015:2>   end
irb(main):016:1> end
=> {"timestamp"=>"2018-01-23T23:48:31.953Z", "fromAddress"=>["Alice", "Another"], "toAddress"=>"Bobz", "amount"=>3}
```

Comment: Your title says filter but I don't see anything about filtering in your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is what you need here.

```
result = @complete_transactions
         .group_by{|hash| hash['toAddress']}
         .map do |key, value|
           {
             'toAddress' => key,
             'amount' => value.sum {|val| val['amount'].to_i},
             'fromAddress' => value.map {|val| val['fromAddress']}.uniq
           }
         end

p result
```

This is for Ruby versions after 2.4.0. For prior versions, calculate the sum of amounts  with this.

```
'amount' => value.map {|val| val['amount'].to_i}.inject(:+)
```

The following statement groups all the hashes by their 'toAddress' values.

```
.group_by{|hash| hash['toAddress']}
```

The followins statement iterates through each of the resulting hash and creates a new hash.

```
.map do |key, value|
```

In the following block, we create our desired hash by operating on the values of each hash.

```
{
  'toAddress' => key,
  'amount' => value.sum {|val| val['amount'].to_i},
  'fromAddress' => value.map {|val| val['fromAddress']}.uniq
}
```

For Ruby versions prior to 2.4.0, the code becomes.

```
{
  'toAddress' => key,
  'amount' => value.map {|val| val['amount'].to_i}.inject(:+),
  'fromAddress' => value.map {|val| val['fromAddress']}.uniq
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `sum` can use a block, no need for `map` there.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Thank you for your suggestion. I've made the change.

Comment: @SimpleLime Yes indeed, that might help. And also, `group_by{|hash| hash['toAddress'].capitalize}` might be more appropriate. But not sure what OP wants here.

Comment: getting `undefined method `sum' for #<Array:0x007f8217a54718>:`

Comment: @Jwan622 This must be because you are using Ruby version before 2.4.0. I have updated the answer to support that as well.

Comment: Very nice solution!

Answer (score 1):

I have written a method that provides what you are asking for but in addition I included something you didn't ask for: the contribution of each "fromAddress" to the total "amount" for each "toAddress". (I misread the question. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯)

**Code**

```
def doit(transactions)
  transactions.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |g,h|
    a = [g["fromAddress"], g["toAddress"]]
    h.update(a => h[a] += g["amount"].to_f)
  end.
  group_by { |(_from, to), _amt| to }.
  map { |k,v| { toAddress: k, amount: v.map(&:last).sum.to_s,
                from_address: v.map { |(from, _to), amt| [from, amt.to_s] }.to_h } }
end
```

**Example**

Let's reduce the example to something more manageable. I've eliminated a number of elements (hashes) of `@transactions` and from each of the hashes that remain I've eliminated the key `"timestamp"` because it's not relevant to the question.

```
transactions = [
  { "toAddress"=>"Alice", "amount"=>"50" },
  { "fromAddress"=>"Alice", "toAddress"=>"Bob", "amount"=>"12.5" },
  { "toAddress"=>"50", "amount"=>"50" },
  { "fromAddress"=>"50", "toAddress"=>"Alice", "amount"=>"50" },
  { "fromAddress"=>"Alice", "toAddress"=>"Alice", "amount"=>"50" },
  { "fromAddress"=>"Alice", "toAddress"=>"Bob", "amount"=>"1" },
  { "fromAddress"=>"1444", "toAddress"=>"0297bc77", "amount"=>"1"},
  { "fromAddress"=>"1444", "toAddress"=>"0297bc77", "amount"=>"1"},
  { "fromAddress"=>"1444", "toAddress"=>"Alice", "amount"=>"1"},
  { "fromAddress"=>"1444", "toAddress"=>"Alice", "amount"=>"2"}
]

doit(transactions)
    #=> [
    #     {:toAddress=>"Alice", :amount=>"153.0",
    #      :from_address=>{nil=>"50.0", "50"=>"50.0", "Alice"=>"50.0", "1444"=>3.0}},
    #     {:toAddress=>"Bob", :amount=>"13.5",
    #      :from_address=>{"Alice"=>"13.5"}},
    #     {:toAddress=>"50", :amount=>"50.0",
    #      :from_address=>{nil=>"50.0"}},
    #     {:toAddress=>"0297bc77", :amount=>"2.0",
    #      :from_address=>{"1444"=>"2.0"}}
    #   ]
```

If you do not wish the return value to contain certain elements you will need to remove the corresponding hashes from `transactions` as the first step (e.g., `transactions.reject { |h| .... }.each_with_object...`).

**Explanation**

The steps are as follows.

```
h = @transactions.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |g,h|
  a = [g["fromAddress"], g["toAddress"]]
  h.update(a => h[a] += g["amount"].to_f)
end
  #=> {[nil, "Alice"]=>50.0, ["Alice", "Bob"]=>13.5, [nil, "50"]=>50.0,
  #    ["50", "Alice"]=>50.0, ["Alice", "Alice"]=>50.0, ["1444", "0297bc77"]=>2.0,
  #    ["1444", "Alice"]=>3.0}
g = h.group_by { |(_from, to), _amt| to }
  #=> { "Alice"=>[[[nil, "Alice"], 50.0], [["50", "Alice"], 50.0],
  #              [["Alice", "Alice"], 50.0], [["1444", "Alice"], 3.0]],
  #     "Bob"=>[[["Alice", "Bob"], 13.5]], "50"=>[[[nil, "50"], 50.0]],
  #     "0297bc77"=>[[["1444", "0297bc77"], 2.0]]}
g.map do |k,v|
  { toAddress: k, amount: v.map(&:last).sum.to_s,
    from_address: v.map { |(from, _to), amt| [from, amt.to_s] }.to_h }
end   
  #=> <return value shown in example>
```