# Most efficient way to filter out elements from an array. Ruby

Tags: ruby

Say I have a list of transactions like so:

```
all = [{"timestamp"=>"2018-01-18T02:57:34.959Z", "toAddress"=>"Alice", "amount"=>"50"},
 {"timestamp"=>"2018-01-18T02:57:35.016Z", "fromAddress"=>"Alice", "toAddress"=>"Bob", "amount"=>"12.5"},
 {"timestamp"=>"2018-01-18T16:53:16.747Z", "toAddress"=>"50", "amount"=>"50"},
 {"timestamp"=>"2018-01-18T16:53:27.572Z", "fromAddress"=>"50", "toAddress"=>"alice", "amount"=>"50"},
 {"timestamp"=>"2018-01-18T16:53:38.853Z", "fromAddress"=>"alice", "toAddress"=>"Alice", "amount"=>"50"},
 {"timestamp"=>"2018-01-23T23:35:03.792Z", "fromAddress"=>"Alice", "toAddress"=>"alice", "amount"=>"10"},
 {"timestamp"=>"2018-01-23T23:35:25.464Z", "fromAddress"=>"Alice", "toAddress"=>"Bob", "amount"=>"1"},
 {"timestamp"=>"2018-01-23T23:35:48.835Z", "fromAddress"=>"Alice", "toAddress"=>"Bob", "amount"=>"1"},
 {"timestamp"=>"2018-01-23T23:47:46.485Z", "fromAddress"=>"Alice", "toAddress"=>"Bob", "amount"=>"1"},
 {"timestamp"=>"2018-01-23T23:48:31.953Z", "fromAddress"=>"Alice", "toAddress"=>"Bobz", "amount"=>"1"},
 {"timestamp"=>"2018-01-24T18:11:04.444Z", "fromAddress"=>"Alice", "toAddress"=>"Bobz", "amount"=>"1"},
 {"timestamp"=>"2018-01-24T18:28:40.680Z", "fromAddress"=>"Alice", "toAddress"=>"bob", "amount"=>"3"},
 {"timestamp"=>"2018-01-24T18:36:53.179Z", "fromAddress"=>"Alice", "toAddress"=>"Sally", "amount"=>"3"},
 {"timestamp"=>"2018-01-24T18:39:14.926Z", "fromAddress"=>"Alice", "toAddress"=>"Sally", "amount"=>"3"},
 {"timestamp"=>"2018-01-24T18:39:40.937Z", "fromAddress"=>"Alice", "toAddress"=>"Sally", "amount"=>"3"},
 {"timestamp"=>"2018-01-24T18:40:11.686Z", "fromAddress"=>"Alice", "toAddress"=>"bob", "amount"=>"2"},
 {"timestamp"=>"2018-01-24T18:40:13.720Z", "fromAddress"=>"Alice", "toAddress"=>"bob", "amount"=>"2"},
 {"timestamp"=>"2018-01-24T18:41:32.832Z", "fromAddress"=>"Alice", "toAddress"=>"bob", "amount"=>"2"},
 {"timestamp"=>"2018-01-24T18:49:10.052Z", "fromAddress"=>"Alice", "toAddress"=>"bob", "amount"=>"2"},
 {"timestamp"=>"2018-01-24T18:49:11.729Z", "fromAddress"=>"Alice", "toAddress"=>"bob", "amount"=>"2"},
 {"timestamp"=>"2018-01-24T18:50:09.862Z", "fromAddress"=>"Alice", "toAddress"=>"bob", "amount"=>"2"},
 {"timestamp"=>"2018-01-24T19:14:46.326Z", "fromAddress"=>"Alice", "toAddress"=>"bob", "amount"=>"2"},
 {"timestamp"=>"2018-01-24T20:29:30.973Z", "fromAddress"=>"Alice", "toAddress"=>"Bob", "amount"=>"3"},
```

...

And it goes on for pages. Is the fastest way to eliminate transactions with an invalid `toAddress` like this:

```
all.select do |t|
   t['toAddress'] != '50'
end
```

How much worse is it to group it by `toAddress` and then filter? Why is it better or worse?

I had something like this in mind:

```
all.group_by do |t|
   t['toAddress']
end.select do |group, trans|
   group != '50'
end
```

From a time complexity standpoint, how much worse is one than the other?

Comment: `Array#reject` is more semantic than `Array#select`.

Comment: `select` and `reject` are both O(n) that seems good for your use case.

Comment: If either if you add an answer, I'll give credit! Maybe add a bit why my group_by + select solution is bad?

Comment: Have you tried benchmarking them? Just run Benchmark#measure

Comment: group has to run through the list once, the select will run through it again, so grouping will almost certainly take longer. Like @sakurashinken said, Benchmark it to be sure.

Comment: [Benchmarks](https://repl.it/@engineersmnky/UnsungHummingWillet) for fun

Comment: @engineersmnky well done, want to write the answer and I'll give you credit?

Comment: What was the point of the whole `class REPL::PatchedStdout
  def sync=(val);end
  def sync; true;end
end`

Comment: @engineersmnky Note that he apparently [wants to group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48493987/how-to-group-and-filter-this-array-of-hashes-ruby). So maybe the group solution shouldn't flatten at the end and the other solutions maybe should group at the end.

Comment: @StefanPochmann I benchmarked this question without knowledge of any other question having been asked. I think I will leave it be as I think it implies the answer to  *"How much worse is it to group it by toAddress and then filter?"*

Comment: @Jwan622 that was simply a patch to allow the benchmark to work in repl.it because benchmark wants `$stdout` to have `sync=` and `sync` methods which  `REPL::PatchedStdout` did not have

Answer (score 0):

Answering this question a bit late probably but here is some result for those who wondering

here is my script to benchmark the different methods

```rb
require 'benchmark'

all = [
  { "timestamp" => "2018-01-18T02:57:34.959Z", "toAddress" => "Alice", "amount" => "50" },
  { "timestamp" => "2018-01-18T02:57:35.016Z", "fromAddress" => "Alice", "toAddress" => "Bob", "amount" => "12.5" },
  { "timestamp" => "2018-01-18T16:53:16.747Z", "toAddress" => "50", "amount" => "50" },
  { "timestamp" => "2018-01-18T16:53:27.572Z", "fromAddress" => "50", "toAddress" => "alice", "amount" => "50" },
  { "timestamp" => "2018-01-18T16:53:38.853Z", "fromAddress" => "alice", "toAddress" => "Alice", "amount" => "50" },
  { "timestamp" => "2018-01-23T23:35:03.792Z", "fromAddress" => "Alice", "toAddress" => "alice", "amount" => "10" },
  { "timestamp" => "2018-01-23T23:35:25.464Z", "fromAddress" => "Alice", "toAddress" => "Bob", "amount" => "1" }
]

50000.times do
  all << { "timestamp" => "2018-01-18T16:53:38.853Z", "fromAddress" => "alice", "toAddress" => "Alice", "amount" => "50" }
  all << { "timestamp" => "2018-01-18T16:53:16.747Z", "toAddress" => "50", "amount" => "50" }
  all << { "timestamp" => "2018-01-18T02:57:34.959Z", "toAddress" => "Alice", "amount" => "50" }

end

Benchmark.bm do |benchmark|
  benchmark.report("select  ") do
    all.select do |t|
      t['toAddress'] != '50'
    end
  end

  benchmark.report("reject  ") do
    all.reject do |t|
      t['toAddress'] == '50'
    end
  end

  benchmark.report("group_by") do
    all.group_by do |t|
      t['toAddress']
    end.select do |group, trans|
      group != '50'
    end
  end
end
```

and here is the output

[image: benchmark]

*EDIT*

I have done the same benchmark but with using the [benchmark/ips](https://github.com/evanphx/benchmark-ips) lib

and this is the result

[image: benchmark with benchmark/ips]